# How to prevent access from VM-Ware to Host machine

Tags: vmware, virtualization

I would like to know if it is possible to prevent access from VM-Ware guest in full screen to the Host machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try remapping the fullscreen escape hotkeys with [AutoHotkey](http://autohotkey.com).

example:

```
!f::return
```

Answer (score 0):

If this was possible, and I think it is not, you won't be able to restart the host machine or handle any problem it has.

And if you plan to hide to the user that he's working on a VmWare you will need to start it automatically when for any reason the guest stopped.

EDIT: You can also set the hotkey combination to something hard to find like Ctrl + Alt + Win + Shift

Answer (score 0):

One completely hilarious way to do that accidentally is to configure the escape key to some key that is not on the particular keyboard.  Easy to do on laptops, that sometimes don't have left and right ctrl or alt.